# Прокси для локальных ресурсов

Tags: linux, сеть

Имеется Linux-машина, на которой стоит несколько виртуалок. Эти виртуалки имеют свой локальный ip, к определенным сервисам должен получать доступ удаленный пользователь. Сразу пришла идея с прокси, но мне нужно что-бы он транслировал не весь трафик, а только туда, где стоят виртуалки.

Comment: удачи в настройке! возможно, вы хотели что-то спросить?

Comment: Я новичок в этом деле, чем такую задачу  можно решить?

Comment: честно говоря, из того, что вы написали в том месте, где должен быть вопрос, складывается впечатление, что вам нужен генератор (каких-то) запросов. какое отношение к нему может иметь виртуальная частная сеть или прокси-сервер, мне, увы, не ясно. задавайте, пожалуйста, конкретные вопросы вместо изложения поставленной перед вами задачи.

Comment: filrewall. он же межсетевой экран, он же брандмауэр. даже в любом домашнем роутере это есть. проброской портов (port forwarding) выполняется доступ интернета к локальным серверам. для доступа к  http-серверам часто применяют reverse proxy. а под простым прокси обычно подразумевается обратная задача - выход из локалки в интернет. и да, firewall шерстит весь трафик. какой транслирует, какой нет - всё настраивается

Comment: 1. вам надо настроить маршрутизацию. 2. включить проброс трафика (`echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`). 3. Если ip виртуалок не доступны снаружи вам надо задать правила iptables для проброса трафика и/или маскарадинга (используя цели iptables: MASQUERADE и возможно SNAT/DNAT). Никаких дополнительных программ обычно устанавливать не нужно.

Comment: я бы поставил впн с проксиарп в локалку виртуалок

Answer (score 1):

Проще каждой из VM назначить свой адрес и не мучится с такими вопросами. Ведь все виртуальные машины это умеют!